# How do you add a CSS class name to an ASP.NET MVC 3 Url.Action link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.MVC 3 or 4 (using Razor), how do you apply a CSS Class to a Url.Action() helper method? Is it possible?

Desired outcome:

```
<a href="home\index?page=2" class="FOO">BAR</a>
```

I have gotten this far:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { page })
```

---

UPDATE: Thanks all. I made a couple of mistakes that I should clarify for future readers (most likely myself). I wish I could give more than one of you credit.

a) new { page } - do not do this. It will produce undesired output. I meant: ViewBag.page or ViewBag.pageNum

b) As a few of you pointed out, I needed Html.ActionLink() not Url.Action() which I had been using successfully until I switched to generating the full tag, not just the url.

I confirmed that the following works as desired:

```
@Html.ActionLink("BAR", "Index", "Home", new { ViewBag.PageNum }, new { @class = "FOO" })
```

Comment: something like this in the `new`: @Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { page, className="foo" })

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I think its `new { @class= '...' }` no?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: I think that will append &class=foo to the url. The answer below seems to be that I need to use ActionLink instead.

Comment: Sorry guys, I definitely need a coffee after lunch, it's NOT className as I said earlier

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you want to use an [`ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505040) instead.  This will allow you to add any attributes you want.

```
@Html.ActionLink("BAR", "Index", "Home", new { page }, new { @class = "FOO" })
```

output:

```
<a href="home/index?page=2" class="FOO">BAR</a>
```

or you can do it "manually"

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { page })" class="FOO">BAR</a>
```

Comment: The second approach Erik mentions above (doing it "manually") is the way to go if you need to nest another tag inside the `<a>` tag (for instance, a `<span>` tag that renders an icon via a font). See [Putting HTML inside Html.ActionLink(), plus No Link Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974980/putting-html-inside-html-actionlink-plus-no-link-text) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Url.Action does not create any html element, it only creates a URL, which is why it's called Url.Action, and not Html.Action... (Html.Action is something totally different).

If you want css on a link that you use Url.Action on, just do this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" class="myclass">My Link<a>
```

Alternatively, you can use Html.ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("My Link", "Action", "Controller", null, new { @class="myclass" })
```

Answer (score 1):

The Url.Action helper will simply print the url not the full anchor.

Your two options are:

```
@Html.ActionLink("BAR", "index","home", new { @class = "FOO" })
```

- note the use of the @ symbol on the class as class is a reserved keyword

and (using the Url.Action helper)

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { page })" class="FOO">BAR</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

I have this class:

```
public class HtmlValues : Dictionary<string,object>
{
    public HtmlValues Class(string ClassName)
    {
        if (this.ContainsKey("class"))
        {
            ClassName = String.Format("{0} {1}", this["class"], ClassName);
            this.Remove("class");
        }
        return this.WithValue("class", ClassName);
    }
    public HtmlValues Name(string Name)
    {
        return this.WithValue("name", Name);
    }
    public HtmlValues Style(string Style)
    {
        return this.WithValue("style", Style);
    }
    public HtmlValues MaxLength(int Length)
    {
        return this.WithValue("maxlength", Length.ToString());
    }
    public HtmlValues RTL()
    {
        return this.WithValue("dir", "rtl");
    }
    public HtmlValues With(string Attribute, string Value)
    {
        return this.WithValue(Attribute, Value);
    }

    public static HtmlValues WithClass(string CssClass)
    {
        return new HtmlValues().Class(CssClass);
    }

    public HtmlValues Data(string key, string value)
    {
        return this.WithValue("data-" + key, value);
    }
}
```

With this extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T WithValue<T>(this T dict, string key, object value) where T : IDictionary<string, object>
    {
        dict.Add(key, value);
        return dict;
    }
}
```

Then my Razor looks like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeProperty, HtmlValues.WithClass("SomeClass"))
```

This may seem like overkill, but it is pretty nice in practice, as it lets you chain add attributes/values to the element in a nice fluent, meaningful to the reader fashion.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeProperty, 
    HtmlValues.WithClass("SomeClass")
              .Class("someotherClass")
              .Data("Some-Jquery-Data-Thing")
              .With("Nonstandard-Attribute","Its-Value"))
```

Comment: Looks like you sort-of rebuilt the [TagBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs).

Comment: @ErikPhilips Well look at that. It'd have been real handy to know about that way back then! Man, 9 years ago already.