# How to add “active” class to Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `_layout.cshtml` like this

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu tree" data-widget="tree">
    <li class="header" style="color:white;font-weight:bold;">Test Menu</li>
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Monney")">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Monney</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Bank")">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Bank</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","User")">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>User</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to add an `"active"` `class` in to `li` when it active to my `sidebar-menu` in MVC.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use Jquery / Javascript ?

Comment: I used Jquery / Javascript before, but the page will reload when I click each `a`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add a CSS class name to an ASP.NET MVC 3 Url.Action link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589128/how-do-you-add-a-css-class-name-to-an-asp-net-mvc-3-url-action-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing if you click on particular link, your page will be refreshed and active class will be remove, if you use jquery. so you need to manage it using Viewbag.

you need to define value in your controller each action.

```
// let say you have User controller

public ActionResult Index()
{
   ViewBag.data = "user";
   return View();
}
```

in your layout you need to check value of that viewbag

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu tree" data-widget="tree">
    <li class="header" style="color:white;font-weight:bold;">Test Menu</li>
    <li id="money">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Monney")">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Monney</span>
        </a>
    </li>
   <li id="bank">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Bank")">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Bank</span>
        </a>
    </li>
   <li id="user">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index","User")">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>User</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ('@ViewBag.data' != null)
        {
           $('#' + '@ViewBag.data').addClass('active');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you need to define viewbag in three controller's index method, or you can create one action fiilter to check controller name and assign value in viewbag

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative way and handle dynamically.

> Create One helper class add following method inside

```
public static  class HtmlExtension
{
    public static string IsActive(this IHtmlHelper html, string controller = null, string action = null, string cssClass = null)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClass))
            cssClass = "active";

        string currentAction = (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        string currentController = (string)html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(controller))
            controller = currentController;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
            action = currentAction;

        return controller.ToLower().Split(',').Contains(currentController.ToLower()) && action.ToLower().Split(',').Contains(currentAction.ToLower()) ?
            cssClass : String.Empty;
    }
}
```

> In cshtml, you need to change

```
 <ul class="sidebar-menu tree" data-widget="tree">
  <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
    <li class="@Html.IsActive("GameVideos", "Index")"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "GameVideos")">videogame</a></li>                                
    <li class="@Html.IsActive("SystemRequirements", "Index")"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SystemRequirements")">systemReq</a></li>
    <li class="@Html.IsActive("Games", "UpcommingGames,Details”)”><a href="@Url.Action("UpcommingGames”, "Games")">upcomming game</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

> Register your helper in web.config for global access.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="YourNameSpace"/> // here you need to add your htmlextension namespace
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

> if you want you can access specific cshtml page

```
@using YourNameSpace // here you need to add your HTML extension namespace
```