# Render span inside action link

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I wonder if there is a way to render html link with inline span iside a link using `HTML.ActionLink`?

The result should be:

```
<a href="Controller/Action">Test<span></span></a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC: Putting HTML inside Html.ActionLink(), plus No Link Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974980/asp-net-mvc-putting-html-inside-html-actionlink-plus-no-link-text)

Comment: All right... I didn't find that.

Answer (score 3):

Not at the moment. However, you could do the following:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("action", "controller")">Test<span></span></a>
```