# How to add a span tag in an a tag using Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

How do you add a `span tag` inside of an `a tag` using `Html.ActionLink`? Is something like this at all possible?

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` together with `Twitter Bootstrap version 3`.

I have a drop down menu and the HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="@(Model.Equals("Home") ? "active" : "")">
          <a href="#">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home
          </a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

I was wanting to do the link like this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
```

But there is a span tag in the mix of things which makes it a bit more complex.

I can probably also use the following:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home
</a>
```

Curious to know if the above is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putting HTML inside Html.ActionLink(), plus No Link Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974980/putting-html-inside-html-actionlink-plus-no-link-text)

Answer (score 2):

Your variant with `Url.Action("Index", "Home")` is correct and possible. `Url.Action` returns the url, so it can be used in a href.