# Razor ActionLink to open Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, actionlink

Can someone help me with this ActionLink I want to open a hidden Div with in Razor,

This is the link,

```
<a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a>
```

And this is the script,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".inline").colorbox({ inline: true, width: "50%" });
    });
</script>
```

And also the Div,

```
<p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a></p>

<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>

        <p><strong>This content comes from a hidden element on this page.</strong></p>

        <p>The inline option preserves bound JavaScript events and changes, and it puts the content back where it came from when it is closed.</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

I need the HTML link re-written in an MVC Razor style ActionLink, the code works fine in HTML, just not in Razor. The HTML link posts to a new page in Razor so I think I need an ActionLink to post to the script.

```
<a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a>
```

e.g..

```
@Html.ActionLink("Inline HTML", null, null, new { Class="inline", onclick = "#inline_content();" });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974980/putting-html-inside-html-actionlink-plus-no-link-text

Answer (score 0):

Your problem only deals with HTML and jQuery. You can show the hidden content by binding a click event to the anchor tag.

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CodingDawg/LTuTt/)

```
$("a.inline").on('click',function(){
    $("#inline_content").parent().show();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Inline HTML", null, null, new { Class="inline", onclick = "Show_Div_content();" });


<script type="text/javascript">
    function Show_Div_content() {
        $("#inline_content").parent().show();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html.ActionLink is part of the LinkExtensions class ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)) which is used to return an anchor element based on parameters passed to it. For me it seems that your only action here is to open up a colorbox.

```
<a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a>
```

Using the above should be fine since your are not routing anything.

Comment: Thanks Michael, My MVC skills are pretty good and I can do this with images using some Javascript called Visual Light Box in Razor but i'm brad new to ColorBox. Should I be using @Url.Content? What is happening, is I end up with a URL ending with /Home/Index/1#inline_content but no ColorBox popup.

Comment: Yeah makes sense since the ActionLink will return a link based on your actual location which at this point is /Home/Index/ since this is not a controller action your are not committing a crime by just using the basic anchor </a> element.