# Hide/Show text in link tag but not the font icon in responsive mode

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, font-awesome

I've got icons set as my navigation bar which is placed horizontally. But I have added after those icons some text that explains what action is associated with the icon.

For example, the 'home' icon from `fa fa-home` (FontAwesome), the text behind this icon 'Home'. The text should only be visible if the browser size is less than `767` pixels in width (twitter bootstrap responsive).

I tried a few ways, but none of them worked, like `$('.navbarText').text().hide();`, `$('a.navbarText').text().hide();`, `$('a text').text().hide();`. I don't recall all my tries though, but tried some pure `CSS` ways too.

I want to avoid adding a `span` or `div` around it.

Any ideas?

[EDIT] some extra info. This is the rendered `html`:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a class="dismissLbl" data-animation="true" data-delay="200" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Go to home page" data-trigger="hover" href="/" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i>Home</a></li>
     <li>
        <a class="dismissLbl" data-animation="true" data-container="body" data-delay="200" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Go to my service(s)" data-trigger="manual hover" href="#" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></i>About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dismissLbl" data-animation="true" data-container="body" data-delay="200" data-placement="bottom" data-title="Go to my deals" data-trigger="manual hover" href="#" rel="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-lg"></i>Contact</a>
    </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

@Hashem Qolami and Brian, when you resize the browser to a smaller size, the horizontally aligned menu will become a button that's placed on the right of the navbar which you can press and the menu opens that looks like an accordion. See the following screenshots for the visual explanation.

[image: normal size, meant for desktop view]
[image: small size, meant for phones, tablets]

As for why I don't want to add a `span` or `div` around it, is because I'm using `@Html.ActionLink("linktext", "actionName")` to render the link, which would require some `jquery` to surround the link tags every time the browser loads or user navigates. Not to mention the checks that have to be done too for every link tag to check whether they are already surrounded or not at every page load or user navigation.

Unnecessary performance loss, if you're asking me.

Comment: `"The text should only be visible if the browser size is less than 767 pixels in width"` do you mean the opposite?

Comment: @Brian I guess so, I'm confused by that statement, why should the text be visible on smaller screens rather than the large ones?

Comment: Just use Url.Action to provide you more control over the dom structure http://stackoverflow.com/a/1975020/1342440 very common

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the following stucture:

```
<a class="dismissLbl" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i> Home
</a>
```

Without adding extra elements, you could achieve that by giving a `font-size` of `0` to anchor tags and then overriding the value on the font icons (nested `<i>` elements):

```css
a.dismissLbl { font-size: 0; }
a.dismissLbl .fa { font-size: 22px; }

/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    a.dismissLbl,
    a.dismissLbl .fa {
        font-size: 16px; /* or whatever you want */
    }
}
```

Finally by using `@media` queries, you could reset the `font-size` to make the text visible on extra small devices.

Comment: This answer is under this assumption that you want to display the text on larger screens and hide that on smaller ones. If you want the opposite, well, you have the logic!

Comment: See my edit in the question, have you named there explicitly about the larger and smaller screen size/browser size.

Comment: @Quoter Fair enough, just one more question, Are you using the font icons by adding `<i>` elements as you've done in your posted snippet?

Comment: @Quoter I've implemented the navbar as you've shown in the question, check this **[Updated Demo](http://jsbin.com/tacugu/1/edit)**.

Comment: that worked perfectly awesome. If you update your questio with this demo, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: to answer your previous question in a comment, I'm using a 3rd party lib that supports chaining in the `View` with `Razor`. This line will produce a link with FontAwesome icon: `@Html.Bootstrap().ActionLink(Resources.Menu.Home, "Index", "Home").Class("dismissLbl").PrependIcon("fa fa-list fa-lg")`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use media queries in your CSS?

```
.text{ display: none; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){ 
  .text{ display: block; }
}
```

Comment: I agree with @AJFarkas, the best way to target that text without using jquery or javascript of any kind its by using media queries (css). If you need and example on how to do this, please post a jsfiddle with your actual code, then I will be able to work from there and give you a working demo.

Comment: FYI, Browser support from media queries summarized here: [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries)

Comment: @AJFarkas, that was my first choice, just couldn't get it to work that way, and I still can't.

Comment: Can I see your CSS? It's hard to help when I'm flying blind. Maybe put the whole thing up on a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and we'll be able to tweak the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with a CSS Media Query and psuedo selectors:

[View the example in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hVFBMq?p=preview)

```
  // Common style for all button icons
  button { color:#000; font-size:24px; paddng:1em; border:none; background:none; cursor:pointer; }
  button:hover { color:#0088CC; }
  button span:after { padding-left:.5em; }

  // Text to display after each icon
  #menu span:after { content:"Menu"; }
  #home span:after { content:"Home"; }
  #mail span:after { content:"Mail"; }
  #account span:after { content:"Account"; }

  // Media Query to hide the text when viewport is less than 767px
  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    button span:after {
      content: ""!important;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have a nice answer, place the CSS regarding the use of content here.

Comment: I added the CSS to this answer...however, it is also available (along with the HTML markup) in the Plunker.

Comment: I would switch `button` to `a` so the questioner can more quickly adapt it to their markup

Comment: @Brian Not sure about `Good practice` as the search engines won't index generated contents. Also using generated contents to display link/navigation text is not flexible; This is the duty of HTML not CSS.

Comment: "good practice" to put your code on your answer :) see previous comments, and please stop targeting me.. this isn't my answer lol

Comment: I know the feeling :)

Comment: @J.C, looks nice, but my menu's are localized. Can't hard code them.

Answer (score 1):

Use the empty() function.

```
$('.navbarText i').empty();
```

Comment: See my reply to genocide_hoax

Comment: Use media queries instead to hide the text. You will probably have to wrap the text in a span though. Bootstrap should also have CSS helper classes to achieve this.

Comment: The problem is, is that the a-tag is generated by the `@Html.ActionLink()` method in `asp.net-mvc`. I can't influence the output.

Comment: What if you add the anchor text inside the fontawesome <i></i> element and then use the jQuery empty() function on that? Not sure how asp.net-mvc works when outputting links.

Comment: simply because once the browser gets resized to a bigger width, there is no text to show. It's a "how to hide/show the text" question.

Answer (score 1):

In case the text is wrapped in a dom element assign a class to it and do the following.

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
   doc_width = $(window).width();
    if(doc_width < 767){
      $(".mytext").hide();
    } else {
      $(".mytext").show();
    }

}
```

I used it in .resize just make it a function .. call it on .ready and .resize.

**Bootstrap Way:**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
   <img src="#" alt="icon">
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-9">
    TEXT
  </div>
</div>
```

Modify it according to your grid system.

Comment: Won't that hide the icons in stead of the text? The text should be visible again if the browser size is bigger than 767 px.

Comment: Oh you want to hide the text. Sorry misread it. If you are using bootstrap you can make use of the .hidden-xs or .hidden-sm class.

Comment: Why using JQuery if this can be done with simple CSS?

Comment: Yup indeed. Bootstrap version also posted. jQuery cause I just love it :P