# how to display &raquo; in ajax.actionlink

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

in an `ajax.actionlink` the first argument is the `"text to display"` which takes a string value, however I'd like to display a `&raquo;` (which displays a nice '>>') however `ajax.actionlink` is displaying a literal '& raquo;' how can I make it display the symbol?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1975020/395890

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An `&raquo;` is `U+00BB`, so the C# escape is `\u00BB`.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been wrong with \x88 - I've changed it.

Comment: strange, /xBB worked though, do you know what the &laquo version is?

Comment: They're all in a table at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/raquo . Use the code from the U+0000 form

Answer (score 5):

You can directly use it, HTML helper will encode it automatically:-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("« Previous","Test",new AjaxOptions 
{
     OnSuccess = "Test"
})

@Ajax.ActionLink("Next »","Test",new AjaxOptions 
{
     OnSuccess = "Test"
})
```

Comment: please elaborate on what you mean by "directly use it", in other words what do I type in for the raquo?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad - I mean the corresponding UTF-8 character of `&raquo`

Comment: @GKFX Ahem... How the duck do you type it in?! (Typo intended.) I vaguely recall some combo with AltGr and a number but I didn't get that to work...

Comment: @Konrad If you only want to type it once, copy-and-paste it off [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raquo). Alt + 174 and Alt + 174 come up on Google if you want to type them repeatedly (on Windows).