# Add bootstrap span tag to a razor actionlink

Tags: html, razor

I would like to add a `<span>` tag to a Razor ActionLink. With regular HTML it looks like:

```
<a href="#">Test <span class="badge">1</span></a>
```

How can I add the span tag to a razor ActionLink like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Test", "Home")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see answer the folloing link:

[Putting HTML inside Html.ActionLink(), plus No Link Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974980/putting-html-inside-html-actionlink-plus-no-link-text)

I hope this help you.

Comment: Please summarize relevant information from links instead of just posting the link by itself.