# Html tag To @Html.ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I tried converting Html tag to @Html.ActionLink

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Login","Signup")" class="button_container header_button ml-auto" data-toggle="modal"><div style="float:right;" class="button text-center"><span>Login</span></div></a>



 @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Signup", null, new { @class = "button_container header_button ml-auto"  })<div style="float:right;" class="button text-center"></div>
```

Comment: <a href="@Url.Action("Login","Signup")" class="button_container header_button ml-auto" data-toggle="modal"><div style="float:right;" class="button text-center"><span>Login</span></div></a>

Comment: What???????????

Comment: With the `ActionLink` helper you cannot nest other HTML elements inside an anchor tag. What is wrong with your first approach? With your expected output, that approach seems to do what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting HTML inside Html.ActionLink(), plus No Link Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974980/putting-html-inside-html-actionlink-plus-no-link-text)

Comment: The first approach is the correct one, you cannot use HTML tags inside `ActionLink` helper - see the provided link for details.